# react-leaflet create a custom components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I would like to create a custom component with react-leaflet that shows the actual position (x,y) of the mouse, but I don't know how to create it. I found `react-leaflet-control` but it seems that it is not up to date, of course I readded the api documentation https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html but I did not understand it :/

Can someone give me an exemple of a custom component please, juste a component that display **"Hello world"** whould be more than enought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html), to create a *custom component* the following steps are required:

1)extend one of the abstract classes provided by `React-Leaflet`, for example:

```
class MapInfo extends MapControl {
   //...
}
```

2)implement `createLeafletElement (props: Object): Object` method to create the relevant Leaflet element instance, for example:

```
createLeafletElement(opts) {
    const MapInfo = L.Control.extend({
      onAdd: (map) => {
        this.panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        return this.panelDiv;
      }
    });
    return new MapInfo({ position: 'bottomleft' });
}
```

3) wrap your custom component using the `withLeaflet()` HOC, for example:

```
export default withLeaflet(MapInfo);
```

The following example demonstrates how create a *custom component* to display the actual position `(lat,lng)` of the mouse on map:

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/p5zzmnlk8j)

Comment: Thanks you very much ! 

Comment: Hello, the Demo doesn't work using react-leaflet v3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

@Vadim Gremyachev asnwer was very useful to me, but I had to spend some more hours with my debugger and react-leaflet's library. Finaly I successfully extended a `CustomMarker` component from react-leaflet's `MapLayer` abstract class. That's originally the base component which react-leaflet's `Marker` extends from. The problem was that initially I had implemented a `componentDidMount` method that shadows the base one. So in addition I had to call inside my method the following line as well.

```
super.componentDidMount()
```

That tells `MapLayer` to attach `this.reactLeaflet` as a layer to leaflet's map.

Entire code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Marker as LeafletMarker } from 'leaflet';
import { MapLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { withLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet';

class CustomMarker extends MapLayer {

  //Whatever leaflet element this function return it will be assigned to this.leafletElement property.
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    let options = this.getOptions(props);
    const el = new LeafletMarker(props.position, options); 
    let layer = props.leaflet.layerContainer;
    let map = props.leaflet.map;
    return el;
  }

  updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
    if(fromProps.someProp != toProps.someProp){
      //Modify this.leafletElement;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    let el = this.leafletElement
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(CustomMarker);
```

You can also implement the `render` method if your component expect to have some children. Check how they do it in react-leaflet's original components, like within `Marker` in the example above.

Comment: Would you please give me one complete example.... maybe on jsfiddle? 
I tried the same way... but still having some difficulties as I am pretty new in react-leaflet. Thank you.

Comment: Tell me what do you exactly want to do and I will try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

For who are using `react-leaflet@4`: it seems that we can use `createControlComponent()` as [documented here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createcontrolcomponent):

```js
const MapInfo = createControlComponent(
  (option) => {
    const MapInfo = L.Control.extend({
      onAdd: (map) => {
        const panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info')
        return panelDiv
      },
    })
    return new MapInfo({ position: 'bottomleft' })
  },
)
```