# Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined - webpack build of react component plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, plugins, components

I'm building a [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) wrapper for my leaflet plugin [leaflet-arrowheads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-arrowheads).  Its a component that I want people to be able to install as an npm package, import, and use.  The component is simple:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet-arrowheads'

class ArrowheadsPolyline extends React.Component{

   componentDidMount(){
      const polyline = this.polylineRef.leafletElement
      if (this.props.arrowheads){
         polyline.arrowheads(this.props.arrowheads)
         polyline._update()
      }
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <Polyline {...this.props} ref={polylineRef => this.polylineRef = polylineRef} />
      )
   }

}

export default ArrowheadsPolyline
```

It works when using this component directly within a project (assuming you have all the same dependencies in installed of course).  I am trying to build this with webpack and publish to npm so that anyone can do a `import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet-arrowheads'` and use the component that way.  My webpack.config looks like this:

```js
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/react-leaflet-arrowheads.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "react-leaflet-arrowheads.js",
        library: "ReactLeafletArrowheads"
    },
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react': {
            commonjs: 'react',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            root: 'React'
        },
        'react-dom': 'commonjs react-dom',
        'leaflet': {
            commonks: 'leaflet',
            commonjs2: 'leaflet',
            root: 'L'
        },
        'react-leaflet': {
            commonjs: 'react-leaflet',
            commonjs2: 'react-leaflet',
            Root: 'ReactLeaflet'
        }
    }
}
```

And my package.json looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "react-leaflet-arrowheads",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A react-leaflet wrapper for leaflet-arrowheads",
  "main": "build/react-leaflet-arrowheads.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "leaflet",
    "react",
    "react-leaflet",
    "arrowheads"
  ],
  "author": "Seth Lutske",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet-arrowheads": "^1.0.11",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.6.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

And then of I course I have my .babelrc which has my babel presets and plugins to properly compile the jsx and what not.  It compiles without issue.  I did an `npm link`, and then linked this to another project to test it out.  In that other project, I have `import { Polyline } from 'react-leaflet-arrowheads'`.  But I get the error message, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined`.  Clearly I am doing something wrong with my webpack build and the way I am handling React.  But I am not sure what.  Is it incorrect to make React (and friends) an `external` in the webpack.config?  Or as a `peerDependency` in the package.json?  The project that this package gets imported into already has and should always already have react as a dependency.  Using webpack to build plugins that become dependencies, but that have their own dependencies, is still something I am learning the subtleties of.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm throwing darts and seeing if any land....

The webpack docs indicate that, to create a library that is available as an ES5 import and a commonJs requires, you need to add `libraryTarget: 'umd'` to the `output` object. I honestly can't say that it doesn't permit `import` without it, but it does say that, without the libraryTarget defined, it defaults to `'var'`, which apparently creates a `var` with the default export results assigned to it.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library

I'm also noticing that the babel-transform-react-jsx plugin isn't included in webpack, but I have no idea if that might be an issue down the line.

Comment: Yes!  This worked!  I swear I had been studying that page of the webpack docs for weeks (the one you linked), trying to understand what the heck was going on there.  Sometimes I feel like their documentation is a bit too concise to really learn.  Your solution worked, but I'm not understanding *why*.  Do you mind elaborating a bit on what is happening here that is resolving the error I was getting?

Comment: Haha not sure it actually explains anything, but apparently, if you don't define how you want to import a file, webpack assumes you want to define it as a variable. I have no idea why they think that makes sense, but they must have their reasons! ‍♂️ Yeah, it really stumped me, because the libraryTarget entry says nothing about the default. Frustrating.

Comment: Oh, so it seems like, if you want it to behave like a real module, not just a variable that has your default output value, you need to define it as a UMD bundle. Apparently that exposes it to be available for ES6 imports as well as CommonJS required() importing.

Comment: This is age-old, but helped me understand the different library target types better: https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/