# React-leaflet `no Context Provided` error when creating 3rd-party plugin

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, vite, react-leaflet

I am trying to build a custom plugin component for [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/), but am running into the same error that [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641585/react-leaflet-custom-component-context-not-being-passed) [others](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/897) [have](https://github.com/TA-Geoforce/react-leaflet-google-v2/issues/17) before me:

```
No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer>
```

I am using Vite's React template for both the library and the application using the library, and have a demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rrvtjz?file=my-component-library%2Fvite.config.ts,demo-app%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx) that shows the error. To replicate:

- Run the Stackblitz (you'll likely need to `npm i` and `npm run build` in `my-component-library/` and then `npm i` and `npm run dev` in `demo-app/`. Note that the map works fine
- Uncomment out the `<Ellipse>` component in `app.tsx` and you'll see the error in the console (may have to refresh the page to see it).

Given that defining the same `<Ellipse>` component inside `demo-app/` works fine, I have concluded that it is an issue with how I'm bundling the library. I followed [these steps](https://dev.to/receter/how-to-create-a-react-component-library-using-vites-library-mode-4lma) to create `my-component-library/`, and it has served me well in the past.

My guess is that it's related to there being multiple/conflicting instances of `react-leaflet`, and I tried to solve that by adding `react-leaflet` and `@react-leaflet/core` to the `external` field in the vite config, but that has not solved the issue.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 10/13**

I have a simpler [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-91p4oe?file=README.md) which demonstrates the issue occuring *only* when using a relative path import (e.g. `npm i ../my-component-library`) and in production mode. Dev mode and installing from a `.tgz` file seems to work fine.