# How to use react-leaflet v3 to create class components?

Tags: react-leaflet

React-leaflet package allows to use leaflet and react using functional components, at least all the examples at https://react-leaflet.js.org/ are using functional components. Is possible to use class components with version 3 of react-leaflet? If yes, there are examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supported to create a *class components* in `react-leaflet v3` although not the same way as it was officially supported in previous versions.

In version `v1` and `v2` you were suppose to implement a custom component by:

a) extending one of the abstract classes provided by `react-leaflet`, for example:

```
class MapInfo extends MapControl {
   //...
}
```

b) and implementing `createLeafletElement (props: Object): Object` method

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067137/1375553) for a more details since official documentation for implementing custom components for v1 and v2 versions is no longer available.

---

**The following example demonstrates how to convert  *custom component* into version `3`.**

Here is an a custom component compatible with v1/v2 version:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withLeaflet, MapControl } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

class MapInfo extends MapControl {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    props.leaflet.map.addEventListener("mousemove", ev => {
      this.panelDiv.innerHTML = `<h2><span>Lat: ${ev.latlng.lat.toFixed(
        4
      )}</span>&nbsp;<span>Lng: ${ev.latlng.lng.toFixed(4)}</span></h2>`;
      console.log(this.panelDiv.innerHTML);
    });
  }

  createLeafletElement(opts) {
    const MapInfo = L.Control.extend({
      onAdd: map => {
        this.panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");
        return this.panelDiv;
      }
    });
    return new MapInfo({ position: "bottomleft" });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
    this.leafletElement.addTo(map);
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(MapInfo);
```

which could be converted into the following class component compatible with version `3`:

```
class MapInfo extends React.Component {
 
  createControl() {
    const MapInfo = L.Control.extend({
      onAdd: (map) => {
        const panelDiv = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info");

        map.addEventListener("mousemove", (ev) => {
          panelDiv.innerHTML = `<h2><span>Lat: ${ev.latlng.lat.toFixed(4)}</span>&nbsp;<span>Lng: ${ev.latlng.lng.toFixed(4)}</span></h2>`;
          console.log(panelDiv.innerHTML);
        });
        return panelDiv;
      },
    });
    return new MapInfo({ position: "bottomleft" });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {map} = this.props;
    const control = this.createControl();
    control.addTo(map);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

function withMap(Component) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const map = useMap();
    return <Component {...props} map={map} />;
  };
}

export default withMap(MapInfo);
```

> **Note:**  `withMap` is a high order component which is intended to pass map instance into class component

[Here is a **demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-http-p8lwj)